# pdfLaTeX problems with figures in Arabi package (Farsi)

Tags: pdftex, babel

I have searched the site with different keywords regarding the aforementioned problem and it seems that I am the first guy with this problem.
I am new to Arabi package. I will use it to typeset Farsi texts, if I could solve this problem.

I use pdfLaTeX to compile my latex files and interestingly, I have no problem if the selected language is English instead of Farsi. In such a case, my figure caption starts with an English phrase "Figure 1:" for example, however in Farsi text I should have some Farsi phrase instead. If I switch to choose Farsi (as usual my texts are in Farsi) I will encounter with this problem:

Edit: replaced included image by a rule of the same size, to produce reproducible example.

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty) [1

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: \pdfrestore: missing \pdfsave
{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex: 1 unmatched \pdfsave after page shipout
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Any help would be appreciated heartily.

My code sample is as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 

\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english,farsi]{babel}
\usepackage[free]{frfonts}

\title{عنوان فارسی}

\begin{document} 

\selectlanguage{farsi}

\section{بخش اول}

\begin{figure}  
\centering
    \resizebox{.7\textwidth}{!}{\rule{532.99126bp}{414.54875bp}}
    \caption{نتایج شبیه‌سازی روش حداکثر نسبت سیگنال به تداخل بعلاوه نویز}
    \label{fig:SINRBF} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, if I 'fix' the above by commenting out `\input{setting}` and adding `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx]` in place of `\usepackage{graphics}` then all is fine.

Comment: @David, and Joseph, Thanks for your comments. In fact, the setting can be commented out, because it is a file containing some definitions which helps me to code the math much easier (in my way and in my opinion). But with 'demo' option of graphicx package, the problem is partially solved. The figure is out there and the caption is also fine (even in Persian) but instead of the actual figure, a black rectangle is printed out. How to solve this issue? I also tested it with Arabic language, and as expected, the same problem experienced again.

Comment: Dear @David, Removing the setting file, does not remove the problem, as the problem is still in the edited code above. But interestingly running the graphicx package with demo option removes the problem. I updated the code now.

Comment: I took the image size reported by pdftex in your original example and replaced by a rule of the same size. I now get the same error so I updated your example and deleted all my earlier comments.  this looks to be an error in the right-to-left support  babel package which is re-ordering pdf internals and making a "restore" come before a "save" and corrupting the command stack.

Answer (score 3):

Using the scaled rule example the error is avoided if I switch to english (ie left to right) just locally.

If wrapping your `\includegraphics` in `{\selectlanguage{english}..}` works then there is at least a workaround for the bug. If not, I'll delete this answer.

I get no error from:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 

\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english,farsi]{babel}
\usepackage[free]{frfonts}

\title{عنوان فارسی}

\begin{document} 

\selectlanguage{farsi}

\section{بخش اول}

\begin{figure}  
\centering
    {\selectlanguage{english}\resizebox{.7\textwidth}{!}{\rule{532.99126bp}{414.54875bp}}}
    \caption{نتایج شبیه‌سازی روش حداکثر نسبت سیگنال به تداخل بعلاوه نویز}
    \label{fig:SINRBF} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @David, It works fine for me and everything looks OK, especially the figure, and the list of figures. Thanks a Million.